# ember-simple-auth: only validate the password without logging in

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

Is it possible to only check the password with ember-simple-auth? I want the user to re-enter their password if they want to delete their account. Can this password check be done without touching the store using ember-simple-auth?

If I use code similar to this:

```
let loginPromise =
    session.authenticate('authenticator:jwt', { identification, password })
return loginPromise.then(() => true).catch(() => false) // allow/deny to delete the account
```

then the session is invalidated if the password is wrong, so the user is signed out. I want, however, to only disable the "Delete Account" button if the password is wrong (without any other side effects like signing in).

Comment: Were you able to solve this case? I am stuck with the same issue for confirmation before changing password

Comment: For now, I am settling for storing the plain text password in `session.data.authenticated.password` after login and comparing it with this when required. If anyone is having better solutions, please let me know.

Comment: No, I wasn't able to really solve this problem. I circumvented it by sending the POST request for a login manually with jQuery. Not elegant at all, but it works.

Comment: For reference (app/services/authenticated-user.js): `Ember.Service.extend({
  ajax: Ember.inject.service();
  validatePassword(username, password) {
    return this.get('ajax').post(`${ENV.host}/users/sign_in`, {
      data: { user: { name: username, password: password } }
    })
  }
  ...
})
`